# Qt: How to use slots when object are created in class function

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, qtquick2, signals-slots

I'm learning Qt quick and want to create a tank game. I create QML components by C++ dynamically. It works great until I use QML signals to connect C++ slots. When the QML emit the signal, C++ fail to receive it and execute the function.

The following code is simplifed.

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    GameMap map;
    map.generateMap();

    return app.exec();
}
```

gamemap.cpp

```
void GameMap::generateMap()
{
    Player player;
    player.generate(&view);

    //QEventLoop loop; //it works when I add these code, but still causes some problems. So I'm wondering if there is other solution?
    //loop.exec();
}
```

player.cpp

```
void Player::generate(View *view)
{
    QQmlComponent component(view.engine(),QUrl("qrc:/Player.qml"));
    QObject *myObject=component.create();
    QQuickItem *item=qobject_cast <QQuickItem*>(myObject);
    QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(item, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
    item->setParentItem(view.rootObject());
    item->setParent(&view);
    QObject::connect(item,SIGNAL(queryCppFun(QString)),this,SLOT(queryFunction(QString)));
}

void Player::queryFunction(const QString &funName)
{
    if(funName=="destroy")
        qDebug()<<funName;
}
```

Player.qml

```
signal queryCppFun(string funName);
function initDestroy(){
    queryCppFun("destroy");
}
```

Comment: First of all this is a very bad idea to handle QML items in C++. This is usually the cause of similar problems. C++ to extend items, not to create. Another note -  you never assign `QQmlApplicationEngine` from the main.cpp to your class.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Sorry for my horrible code, the reason why I type like this is because it is C++ homework, and I found that if I create items in QML, there won't be a single line of C++ code. So I get goal in roundabout way

Answer (score 0):

OK, I know how to do with it.

Just put static in front of `Player player;`

And do not handle QML items in C++, thanks @folibis